Partytown GTM/GA4 on wordpress site
I would like to implement GTM/GA4 in WordPress with WooCommerce using the Partytown library without plugins. Unfortunately, after the implementation, GTM does not see the container and, therefore, does not collect any information.
The library is integrated, and the code looks as follows:
<script>
        partytown = {
            lib: '/~partytown/',
            forward: ['dataLayer.push'],
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/~partytown/partytown.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script type="text/partytown">(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXX"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'G-XXXXX');
    </script>

Here, for now, it's just GTM, but I know that the GA4 code can also have the attribute type="text/partytown" added. I need help to determine if this library works at all and how to implement it properly. This code is in my header.php file.

I would suggest you to put the code directly inside the header through either Appearances > Theme File Editor or through the File Editors by editing the head files.

Yeah, this code is in my header.php. And still not working...
